# What is a good way to place multiple buttons over an image in html5?

Tags: html, image, button, position

I'd like to do this without specifying what the size of the image is every time, and I'd like to work anywhere this is placed on a page.

What I've tried is using the figure tag and playing an image and buttons with relative positions inside.

```
<figure>

<img src="myImage.jpg">

<button style='position:relative; left:0px; bottom:0px' type='button'>+</button>

<button style='position:relative; left:0px; bottom:50px' type='button'>+</button>

</figure>
```

I'm not sure what I changed because that used to place the plus signs over the image, but now it places it next to the image. Also, the second button I'd expect to be vertically directly over the first, but there's space to the left of it.

Answer (score 0):

exact left and top would depend upon image size . both buttons should have position absolute.

apply below css to button

```
.btnClass{
position: absolute;
left: 150px;
top: 160px;
}
```

here left and top should be half the width and height of your image , I have placed some sample values

find fiddle for this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BHUPENDRA1011/f4AZL/) ;

Comment: Thanks for your hard work, but I'd like this to work anywhere on the page, meaning if there was content above this, this wouldn't mess up the button positions. I'd like it to be relative to something inside the <figure> tags, if not a corner of the image.

Comment: buttons needed to positioned absolute , by absolute it would be removed from normal flow of DOM , and you can float them anywhere whereas relative will not remove them flow OF DOM , so space occupied by them wont be empty